# Distribution of Additive combination of normal RVs

Tags: probability

For a linear combination of independent normal RVs $\{Z_i\}_{i=1}^n,$ e.g.
$$
Y = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i Z_i, \qquad Z_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2), \qquad c_i \in \mathbb{R},
$$
we know
$$
Y \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n c_i \mu_i, \sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2 \sigma_i^2\right).
$$

Now, again for independent standard normal RVs, what is the distribution of the following random variable?
$$
Y = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i Z_i^2
$$

Also, what is the distribution of a "mixed" case? E.g.,
$$
Y = c_1Z_1 + c_2 Z_2^2
$$

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As you don't assume IID, chi-square distribution is out of the window. I find this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89779/sum-of-squares-of-normal-distributions) most helpful.

Comment: Actually, it seems like the noncentral $\chi^2$ distribution should work for the sum of the squares, no?  Even with different distributions for the $Z_i$?  Thanks for thinking of that.

Comment: @bcf No, chi-square requires IID$\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$, and can be generalized to IID$\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$. I didn't know anything beyond that, until I found Mathai and Provost (this is some knowledge beyond wikipedia).